# Trying to copy specific (or all) sheets from active workbook to another existing workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Dim input_Path As String
    Dim summary_file As String

    input_Path = Sheet1.TextBox1.Text
    Workbooks.Open input_Path

    summary_file = Sheet1.TextBox3.Text
    Workbooks.Open summary_file

    Worksheets(Array("Summary", "Top Reasons")).Copy after:=Workbooks(input_Path).Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

End sub
```

Trying to copy specific sheets from active workbook to another existing workbook. Both the workbooks are opened through folder picker with variable.

i am unable to copy the sheets.

can someone pls help

Comment: What workbook do “Summary" and "Top Reasons” worksheets belong to?

Comment: While from your code it seems that input_Path and summary_file are taken from sheet textboxes snd not from filepickfolder as your narrative says

Answer (score -1):

Try:

For each worksheet in Workbooks("yourworkbook").worksheets

Your CopyCode

Next Worksheet